running java tests in devcontainer with selenium grid
I am trying to setup a devcontainer for Java based automation testing with Selenium Grid.
So far I have the docker-compose-v3.yml from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml running on my local workstation. I can run my Java Selenium project by pointing http://localhost:4444.
Now, I want to make this project run inside a devcontainer.
For this purpose, I have devcontainer.json file like this:
{
  "name": "basic-project",
  "build": {
    dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
  },
  "dockerComposeFile": [
    "selenium-hub-docker.yml"
  ],
  "service": "selenium-hub",
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/java:1": {
      "version": "11",
      "installMaven": "true"
    }
  },
  "customizations": {
    "jetbrains": {
      "backend": "IntelliJ"
    },
    "codespaces": {
      "openFiles": [
        "README.md"
      ]
    },
    "vscode": {
      "extensions": [
        "alphabotsec.vscode-eclipse-keybindings",
        "ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "maven.pomfile.prefetchEffectivePom": true
      }
    }
  }
}

the Dockerfile contents:
FROM openjdk:11
LABEL authors="adrianherscu"

and, the selenium-hub-docker.yml contents:
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.21.0
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "7900:7900"
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.21.0
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "7902:7900"
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.21.0
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"


All the above is in one of my Github repos at: https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git, on the selenium-hub-docker branch.
Now, I am trying to run it via IntelliJ, by cloning, and getting:
Connecting to Docker...
Connecting to Docker... Connected
Reuse sources volume from the previous dev container.
Setting up container features:
Downloading java feature manifest...
Creating directory /var/home/adrianherscu/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/java
Writing file /var/home/adrianherscu/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/java/NOTES.md
Writing file /var/home/adrianherscu/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/java/NOTICE.txt
Writing file /var/home/adrianherscu/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/java/README.md
Writing file /var/home/adrianherscu/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/java/devcontainer-feature.json
Writing file /var/home/adrianherscu/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/java/install.sh
Writing file /var/home/adrianherscu/.cache/JetBrains/DevContainers/devcontainers/features/java/wrapper.sh
Creating jb-devcontainer-features-25e0c2226828cf635710bee8f685e786...
Building image…
Preparing build context archive…
[==================================================>]10/10 files
Done

Sending build context to Docker daemon…
[==================================================>] 26.09kB
Done

Step 1/2 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2/2 : COPY . /tmp/jb-devcontainer-features
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3031919254b1

Successfully built 3031919254b1
Successfully tagged jb-devcontainer-features-25e0c2226828cf635710bee8f685e786:latest
WARN[0000] /var/home/adrianherscu/Projects/basic-project/.devcontainer/selenium-hub-docker.yml: `version` is obsolete 
[+] Running 1/1
 ! selenium-hub Warning pull access denied for jb-devcontainer-d47234a3ad8d0d053d3087b4c13e776, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied2.4s 
[+] Building 38.8s (8/8) FINISHED                                docker:default
 => [selenium-hub internal] load build definition from .features.temp.doc  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.59kB                                     0.0s
 => [selenium-hub internal] load metadata for docker.io/selenium/hub:4.21  0.0s
 => [selenium-hub internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/jb-devcon  0.0s
 => [selenium-hub internal] load .dockerignore                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [selenium-hub] FROM docker.io/library/jb-devcontainer-features-25e0c2  0.0s
 => [selenium-hub stage-0 1/3] FROM docker.io/selenium/hub:4.21.0          0.0s
 => CACHED [selenium-hub stage-0 2/3] COPY --from=jb-devcontainer-feature  0.0s
 => ERROR [selenium-hub stage-0 3/3] RUN chmod -R 0755 /tmp/jb-devcontai  38.7s
------
 > [selenium-hub stage-0 3/3] RUN chmod -R 0755 /tmp/jb-devcontainer-features/ghcr.io-devcontainers-features-java-1 && cd /tmp/jb-devcontainer-features/ghcr.io-devcontainers-features-java-1 && chmod +x ./devcontainer-feature-setup.sh && ./devcontainer-feature-setup.sh:
0.192 Installing java feature...
0.208 find: '/var/lib/apt/lists/*': No such file or directory
0.209 Running apt-get update...
0.487 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
0.624 Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
1.093 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]
1.288 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
1.394 Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [1089 kB]
2.488 Get:6 https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb jammy InRelease [7504 B]
2.608 Get:7 https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb jammy/main amd64 Packages [9493 B]
2.812 Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [1889 kB]
3.861 Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
29.25 Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1389 kB]
32.24 Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [2160 kB]
34.64 Fetched 26.3 MB in 34s (765 kB/s)
34.64 Reading package lists...
35.29 Reading package lists...
35.92 Building dependency tree...
36.04 Reading state information...
36.24 findutils is already the newest version (4.8.0-1ubuntu3).
36.24 sed is already the newest version (4.8-1ubuntu2).
36.24 ca-certificates is already the newest version (20230311ubuntu0.22.04.1).
36.24 tar is already the newest version (1.34+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1.22.04.2).
36.24 unzip is already the newest version (6.0-26ubuntu3.2).
36.24 util-linux is already the newest version (2.37.2-4ubuntu3.4).
36.24 The following NEW packages will be installed:
36.24   zip
36.32 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
36.32 Need to get 176 kB of archives.
36.32 After this operation, 544 kB of additional disk space will be used.
36.32 Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 zip amd64 3.0-12build2
37.62 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 zip amd64 3.0-12build2 [176 kB]
38.38 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
38.40 Fetched 176 kB in 2s (87.4 kB/s)
38.41 Selecting previously unselected package zip.
38.41 (Reading database ... (Reading database ... 5%(Reading database ... 10%(Reading database ... 15%(Reading database ... 20%(Reading database ... 25%(Reading database ... 30%(Reading database ... 35%(Reading database ... 40%(Reading database ... 45%(Reading database ... 50%(Reading database ... 55%(Reading database ... 60%(Reading database ... 65%(Reading database ... 70%(Reading database ... 75%(Reading database ... 80%(Reading database ... 85%(Reading database ... 90%(Reading database ... 95%(Reading database ... 100%(Reading database ... 9150 files and directories currently installed.)
38.41 Preparing to unpack .../zip_3.0-12build2_amd64.deb ...
38.45 Unpacking zip (3.0-12build2) ...
38.50 Setting up zip (3.0-12build2) ...
38.55 usermod: user '1200' does not exist
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c chmod -R 0755 /tmp/jb-devcontainer-features/ghcr.io-devcontainers-features-java-1 && cd /tmp/jb-devcontainer-features/ghcr.io-devcontainers-features-java-1 && chmod +x ./devcontainer-feature-setup.sh && ./devcontainer-feature-setup.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 6
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17

Via VSCode, I am getting:
[39 ms] Dev Containers 0.369.0 in VS Code 1.90.0 (89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573).
[39 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[48 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[49 ms] Start: Run: docker version
[88 ms] Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           26.1.4
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.21.11
 Git commit:        5650f9b
 Built:             Wed Jun  5 11:31:00 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          26.1.4
  API version:      1.45 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.11
  Git commit:       de5c9cf
  Built:            Wed Jun  5 11:29:16 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.33
  GitCommit:        d2d58213f83a351ca8f528a95fbd145f5654e957
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
[92 ms] Start: Run: docker volume ls -q
[116 ms] Start: Run: docker build -f /tmp/vsch-adrianherscu/bootstrap-image/0.369.0/bootstrap.Dockerfile -t vsc-volume-bootstrap /tmp/vsch-adrianherscu/bootstrap-image/0.369.0
[+] Building 0.8s (13/13) FINISHED                               docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from bootstrap.Dockerfile             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.08kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:0-a  0.7s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [1/8] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:0-alpine-3.16@sha256:  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 223.52kB                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] COPY host-ca-certificates.crt /tmp/host-ca-certificates.  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] RUN cat /tmp/host-ca-certificates.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/  0.0s
 => CACHED [4/8] RUN csplit -f /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/host-ca-c  0.0s
 => CACHED [5/8] RUN echo "@old https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.  0.0s
 => CACHED [6/8] RUN apk add --no-cache  git-lfs  nodejs  python3  npm  m  0.0s
 => CACHED [7/8] RUN npm config set cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates  0.0s
 => CACHED [8/8] COPY .vscode-remote-containers /root/.vscode-remote-cont  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:451057877bfa64fc3c6088d9ded464994a3cfcfb80ddb  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/vsc-volume-bootstrap                    0.0s
[1118 ms] Cloning Github repository: QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project into /workspaces/basic-project

[1118 ms] Start: Run: docker run -d --mount type=volume,src=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a,dst=/workspaces -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock vsc-volume-bootstrap sleep infinity
[1486 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[1494 ms] Start: Launching Dev Containers helper.
[1495 ms] ssh-agent: SSH_AUTH_SOCK in container (/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16.sock) forwarded to local host (/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh).
[1495 ms] Start: Run in container: test -e /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
[1567 ms] 
[1567 ms] 
[1567 ms] Exit code 1
[1568 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p '/tmp/.X11-unix'
[1569 ms] 
[1569 ms] 
[1569 ms] X11 forwarding: DISPLAY in container (:0) forwarded to local host (:0).
[1570 ms] Start: Run in container: gpgconf --list-dir agent-socket
[1571 ms] /root/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
[1571 ms] 
[1572 ms] Start: Run in container: gpgconf --list-dir homedir
[1573 ms] /root/.gnupg
[1573 ms] 
[1573 ms] Start: Run in container: ls '/root/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d' 2>/dev/null
[1575 ms] 
[1575 ms] 
[1575 ms] Exit code 2
[1575 ms] Start: Run: gpgconf --list-dir agent-extra-socket
[1581 ms] /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
[1581 ms] 
[1581 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p -m 700 '/root/.gnupg'
[1581 ms] gpg-agent: Socket in container (/root/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent) forwarded to local host (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra).
[1583 ms] 
[1584 ms] 
[1584 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v docker >/dev/null 2>&1
[1584 ms] Start: Run: gpgconf --list-dir homedir
[1587 ms] 
[1588 ms] 
[1588 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[1592 ms] Start: Run in container: echo ~
[1593 ms] /var/home/adrianherscu/.gnupg
[1593 ms] 
[1593 ms] Start: Run in container: gpgconf --list-dir homedir
[1595 ms] /root/.gnupg
[1595 ms] 
[1598 ms] Start: Run in container: # Test for /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg and gpg
[1600 ms] 
[1600 ms] 
[1600 ms] Start: Run in container: # Copy /var/home/adrianherscu/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg to /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg
[1602 ms] 
[1603 ms] 
[1603 ms] Start: Run: gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye
[1658 ms] /root
[1658 ms] 
[1658 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16.js
[1659 ms] 
[1660 ms] 
[1660 ms] Start: Run in container: cat ~/.docker/config.json || echo "{
[1662 ms] {
}
[1662 ms] cat: /root/.docker/config.json: No such file or directory
[1662 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /usr/local/bin && cat <<'EOF-/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-dev-containers-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16' >/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-dev-containers-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16
[1665 ms] 
[1665 ms] 
[1665 ms] Start: Run in container: chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-dev-containers-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16
[1666 ms] 
[1666 ms] 
[1667 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p ~/.docker && cat <<'EOF-/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-dev-containers-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16' >~/.docker/config.json
[1669 ms] 
[1669 ms] 
[1669 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16.js_1718042945791
[1672 ms] 
[1672 ms] 
[1674 ms] Start: Run in container: # Test for /root/.gitconfig and git
[1676 ms] 
[1676 ms] 
[1676 ms] Start: Run in container: # Copy /var/home/adrianherscu/.gitconfig to /root/.gitconfig
[1678 ms] 
[1678 ms] 
[1679 ms] Start: Run in container: # Cleaning up git config
[1683 ms] 
[1684 ms] 
[1684 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --global --replace-all credential.helper '!f() { node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-4dccc05f-544c-4f4f-92e1-07b392422f16.js git-credential-helper $*; }; f' || true
[1685 ms] 
[1685 ms] 
[1686 ms] Start: Run in container: # Test for /root/.ssh/known_hosts and ssh
[1688 ms] 
[1688 ms] 
[1688 ms] Start: Run in container: # Copy /var/home/adrianherscu/.ssh/known_hosts to /root/.ssh/known_hosts
[1690 ms] 
[1690 ms] 
[1779 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json 2>/dev/null
[1781 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json 2>/dev/null
[1783 ms] Start: Run in container: test -e "/var/home/adrianherscu" || (mkdir -p "$(dirname "/var/home/adrianherscu")" && ln -s ~ "/var/home/adrianherscu")
[1786 ms] 
[1786 ms] 
[1786 ms] Start: Run in container: docker volume ls -q
[1972 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --filter label=vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --filter label=vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[2044 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --filter label=vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --filter label=vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[2111 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --filter label=vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --filter label=vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project
[2181 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --filter label=vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --filter label=vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project
[2251 ms] Running Dev Containers CLI:   read-configuration --workspace-folder /workspaces/basic-project --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --mount-workspace-git-root
[2433 ms] Start: Run in container: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /workspaces/basic-project --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --mount-workspace-git-root
[2818 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.62.0. Node.js v16.20.2. linux 6.8.11-200.fc39.x86_64 x64.
[2818 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --filter label=vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --filter label=vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[3261 ms] Running Dev Containers CLI:   up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-e63116ea-ddc6-4ec4-9a74-b56498125b901718042943517 --workspace-folder /workspaces/basic-project --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=/run/user/1000/wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-ed67d454-343a-420c-8c8e-f42bf0afa32d.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root
[3261 ms] Start: Run in container: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-e63116ea-ddc6-4ec4-9a74-b56498125b901718042943517 --workspace-folder /workspaces/basic-project --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=/run/user/1000/wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-ed67d454-343a-420c-8c8e-f42bf0afa32d.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root
[3571 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.62.0. Node.js v16.20.2. linux 6.8.11-200.fc39.x86_64 x64.
[3571 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx version
[3635 ms] github.com/docker/buildx v0.8.2 6224def4dd2c3d347eee19db595348c50d7cb491
[3635 ms] 
[3636 ms] Start: Run: docker -v
[3653 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[3893 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose version --short
[3896 ms] Start: Run: docker compose version --short
[3949 ms] Docker Compose version: 2.12.2
[3950 ms] Start: Run: docker compose -f /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/selenium-hub-docker.yml --profile * config
[4003 ms] name: devcontainer
services:
  chrome:
    depends_on:
      selenium-hub:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST: selenium-hub
      SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT: "4442"
      SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT: "4443"
      VNC_NO_PASSWORD: "1"
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.21.0
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 7900
      published: "7900"
      protocol: tcp
    shm_size: "2147483648"
  firefox:
    depends_on:
      selenium-hub:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST: selenium-hub
      SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT: "4442"
      SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT: "4443"
      VNC_NO_PASSWORD: "1"
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.21.0
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 7900
      published: "7902"
      protocol: tcp
    shm_size: "2147483648"
  selenium-hub:
    container_name: selenium-hub
    image: selenium/hub:4.21.0
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 4442
      published: "4442"
      protocol: tcp
    - mode: ingress
      target: 4443
      published: "4443"
      protocol: tcp
    - mode: ingress
      target: 4444
      published: "4444"
      protocol: tcp
networks:
  default:
    name: devcontainer_default
[4009 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=basic-project_devcontainer --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=undefined
[4027 ms] Error: Service 'undefined' configured in devcontainer.json not found in Docker Compose configuration.
[4028 ms]     at QtA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:429:1542)
[4028 ms]     at utA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:409:3512)
[4028 ms]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[4028 ms]     at async KtA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:3865)
[4028 ms]     at async eB (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:4807)
[4028 ms]     at async hrA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:13373)
[4028 ms]     at async lrA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:13114)
[4035 ms] Exit code 1
[4035 ms] Start: Run: docker rm -f 3a06af2e74f87a59213b028e03ae75040e29e0c8e34c1b42b2dd1e9603c926ef
[4043 ms] Command failed: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.369.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-e63116ea-ddc6-4ec4-9a74-b56498125b901718042943517 --workspace-folder /workspaces/basic-project --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/QA-Automation-Starter/basic-project.git/tree/selenium-hub-docker --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=basic-project --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/basic-project/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=basic-project-selenium-hub-docker-65e7d83c2f25b6574621a7d89192fd627d70def9061746e895740c734f4b6f3a,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=/run/user/1000/wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-ed67d454-343a-420c-8c8e-f42bf0afa32d.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root
[4043 ms] Exit code 1
[4075 ms] Container server terminated (code: 137, signal: null).

Any suggestions?
TIA,
Adrian.

Added to compose file, under "services" section:
  tests:
    image: openjdk:11
    command: sleep infinity

and changed "service":
  "service": "tests",

removed the "build" section.
It now opens correctly in IntelliJ but still fails in VSCode.
